# PyGame: Economic way of handling game loops

Tags: python, pygame

I coded a small script using pygame (actually not a video game, but a graphical display for simulation results if that matters) but I'm not really satisfied with it's way of waiting for user events (in my case I'm only interested in a few keys on the keyboard).

It uses a:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #tests and hypothetical actions
```

This loops will saturate a CPU core even if the users doesn't do anything, which means useless stress on the CPU, heat, fan noise, maybe lags. Is there a smarter, ie. more economic, way of putting the program in waiting mode for events without using an infinite loop, but still using pygame.

Comment: I doubt that any thing someone makes on an individual level can __saturate__ a CPU core.

Comment: @sshashank124: Well what I mean by saturate is using it @ 100% , which,I just double checked, it does.

Comment: I think the closest you can get is by adding a `timer.tick()` method to control the max FPS. Other than that, I am not aware of any ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that you can do is to block events that you are not going to use:

```
pygame.event.set_allowed(None)
pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.QUIT, pygame.KEYDOWN])
```

This will only post events such as `pygame.QUIT` and `pygame.KEYDOWN` onto the queue.

If there are no new key presses, there is nothing in the event queue, so the loop is not executed.

As sshashhank124 said in the comments, you can also slow the the main loop, by calling

```
clock.tick(frames)
```

This will cause pygame to sleep for some time so that the method tick will be called frames times per second.

Comment: I would add that `pygame.event.wait()` can be used instead of `get()/tick()` combination, to wait for events. But it will prevent the program from updating the screen which can result in a black screen.

Comment: Thank you, adding a: `clock.tick(10)` solved my problem (I also added your event filter). Many thanks again ;)